# Simplest way to tell if two logical drives on the same device?

Tags: hard-drive, storage-area-network

What is the simplest way to determine whether 2 logical drives are on the same device?

I have access to remote into the server, but the hosting company isn't reasonably accessible for me to ask the question directly. One method would be to see whether operations run on each drive simultaneously negatively impacts the other. But is there some way to determine more simply just by looking at some device properties or anything like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a SAN, no. In principle it is possible to set up virtual disks so no properties will match, so even looking at properties won't help.

Comparing the performance of one disk while other is loaded or idle is actually the only way to even tell whether they share something or not. Check also that you are not just saturating the SAN link.

If your contract with the hosting has a SLA with written minimal disk performance, you can measure that and if it is less than expected, you can complain to them due to breach of SLA.

Comment: Thanks. I don't suspect there is a breach, but was just wanting to know whether moving a SQL Server TempDB to another drive would actually accomplish anything. I did end up just doing some file copies with large files while watching Task Manager. And let's just say I was disappointed, lol. Oh well.